# After Windows Update none of the websites work anymore

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

On friday I installed windows updates - I guess this was not good at all.

All my websites return now error 500. So I checked Windows Event Viewer, there are two error logs:

```
Source: ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
An error occured while trying to start an integrated application 
instance. 
Exception:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070700 
StackTrace: at System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostSupportFunctions.GetConfigToken(String appId)....
```

and the second one:

```
Source: IIS-W3SVC-WP
An Application has reported as being unhealthy. The worker process will now request a cycle. Reason given: ASP.NET application initialization failed.. The data is the error.
In Details there is the reason: ASP.NET application initialization failed. 00070780
```

I read, I need to check for the service "Netlogon". This service is state "Stopped" and when I'm trying to restart it, it still changes after "Starting" to "Stopped"

I already tried iisreset, restarting server,.. nothing helped. Any idea for a non-professional? My next step would be reinstalling windows on my v-server - I really don't want to.

Edit: I just remembered, I changed the administrators password on the hosters website. Seems like this destroyed my AD.

Comment: Starting the netlogon service should create new events in the event viewer.

Comment: And before I'd reinstall the server I'd return to the snapshot of the VM I took before installing the updates, or at least uninstall the installed updates.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes it creates new events but they're not different to the existing ones. Mhh yeah I don't have any snapshot. I have a backup, but this is from saturday since I configured the backups wrong.- I already took the backup from saturday but makes no difference...

Comment: Uninstall the updates, reboot and try again. Sometimes updates do contain bugs, so your first focus should be which update is the culprit.

Comment: Updated. It's clearly a problem with AD after changing the admins password on online control panel of my hoster

Comment: What leads you to conclude that changing the admin password of the online control panel "destroyed" Active Directory?

Comment: @DougDeden no, I didnt change the password for my control panel but I changed the password for windows administrator inside the control panel. The control-panels password-changing-function doesn't change a password in the active directory, and this is what I missed.